# Error -32 EPIPE broken pipe

Tags: asp.net-core

I am doing a post request with ajax that should return a partialview but I always get following error in log:

```
Connection id "0HL6PHMI6GKUP" communication error.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -32 EPIPE broken pipe
```

When looking at the debug log, I see that it is loading the partialview data but than I get the error.

I can't find anything on the net about the -32 EPIPE error, could someone help me explain what this error means?

**Ajax call**

```
$( "#PostForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

    //Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/url/path/CreateBox", 
        data: {
            "id": $("#RackId").val(),
            "Name": $("#Name").val()
        },
        success: function(result){
            $("#modal").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateBox(int id, string Name)
{
    //Get the info of the given ID
    Rack rack = await this._rackAccess.GetByIdAsync(id);
    if (rack == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    Box box = new Box();
    box.Rack = rack;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
    {
        box.Name = Name;

        var result = await this._boxAccess.InsertAsync(box);

        //Returns a list of boxes
        return PartialView("Boxes", await this._boxAccess.ToRackListAsync(rack.ID));
    }else{
        //Returns form again
        return PartialView("CreateBox", box);
    }
}
```

**Version**

```
Aspnet core: 1.1.0

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0"
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.1.0",
```

Comment: Is this happen all time or some time ? Can you please put some code that display controller and any specific configuration you have did in configure and configureservice method ? Another suggestion is that please try to return something else from controller action ?

Comment: It happens all the time. I added the controller method in the question. The method is able to call the partialview "boxes" (I can see this in the logs because it is fetching localization data that is called in the boxes partial view) + the data was successfully inserted in the database. Nothing special was added to configureservice. I also tested it with a simple partialView "Test" that only returns "this is a test", but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found on github were I posted the problem aswell:
https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1978

**Answer of halter73 on github:**

The "communication error" usually comes in ECONNRESET, EPIPE, and ECANCELED varieties. Which one you get usually just depends on which platform you're running on, but all three generally mean the same thing: that the client closed the connection ungracefully.

I have a theory why this is happening. I think that the page might be getting reloaded mid-xhr causing the xhr to get aborted. This can be fixed by returning false from your jQuery submit callback.

I took all your dependencies and your jQuery snippet and demonstrated how this page reload can cause an EPIPE on linux and an ECANCELED on Windows in a sample repro at https://github.com/halter73/EPIPE. It uses csproj instead of project.json because I don't have an old CLI that supports project.json easily available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to long time processing on server-side,
communication pipe was broken by overtime mechanism.

Wish this is helpful.